# Minimal BST File That Writes Something

Tags: bibtex, examples, minimal

For [another question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174512/wrapping-add-period), I am trying to create a minimal BibTeX style that writes something into the output file.

I am following the instructions from the [manual](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~markey/BibTeX/doc/ttb_en.pdf) (page 35), where a minimal example is indicated as

```
ENTRY {}{}{}

FUNCTION {test}
{"de la Cierva y Codorn{\’\i}u, Juan"
#1 "{ff - }{vv - }{ll}" format.name$ top$}

READ

EXECUTE{test}
```

So, as a minimal setup, I created these files:

**test.tex**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

This is a statement backed with a reference~\cite{Example}.

\bibliographystyle{test}
\bibliography{test}

\end{document}
```

**test.bib**

```
% This file was created with JabRef 2.6.
% Encoding: UTF8

@ARTICLE{Example,
  author = {Sally Sample and Eddie Example},
  title = {An Example Paper For Your Bibliography},
  journal = {International Journal of Exemplary Text Fragments},
  year = {2012},
  volume = {3},
  pages = {42--49},
  owner = {haagfn},
  timestamp = {2014.05.02}
}
```

**test.bst**

```
ENTRY {}{}{}

FUNCTION {output.something}
{
  "test" write$
}

READ

EXECUTE {output.something}
```

According to the [manual](http://www.lsv.ens-cachan.fr/~markey/BibTeX/doc/ttb_en.pdf), the `write$` command

> write[s] *S* in the output `.bbl` file.

(with *S* being the item on the stack right below `write$`)

For compilation, I'm using these commands:

```
pdflatex test.tex
bibtex test.aux
pdflatex test.tex
bibtex test.aux
pdflatex test.tex
```

However, my `.bbl` file remains empty. Oddly, when I replace `write$` with `top$` (as in the example from the manual), *test* does get output in the terminal. However, to make my example as true to the real use case as possible (and also because I want to know how it works), I would like to output my example string to the `.bbl` file.

**Why does my `.bbl` file remain empty and what do I have to change so *test* gets output there?**

Comment: Your demo shows `test.bbl`: I assume you mean the input is in `test.bst`

Comment: @JosephWright: Whoops, of course. Thanks, corrected. Got confused with the file extensions while writing the question, the actual file is indeed named `test.bst`.

Answer (score 5):

You should write in the `.bst` file

```
"test" write$ newline$
```

not only

```
"test" write$
```

Comment: Indeed! Welcome to TeX.SX!